# Conditional validation in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using VueJS with vue-validator and I have been struggling for hours to do simple conditional validation. The example provided in the documentation does not seem to work, at least not in my case.

What I am trying to accomplish is requiring two input groups (`observer_firstName` and `observer_lastName`) if a condition (`showObserverEntry`) is `true` and requiring another (`role`) if it is `false`.

So, if `showObserverEntry` is `false`, `role` should be required/visible. If `showObserverEntry` is `true`, `role` SHOULD NOT be required or visible, `observer_firstName` and `observer_lastName` should be required and visible.

Everything works when the page is loaded and `showObserverEntry` is set to `false`, it continues to work when switched to `true`, but when it goes back to `false` again validation stops working for `role`. Peeking at the data output, the validation data changes to `validation { }` where it initially has data.

Vue instance with other methods removed:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#scheduleContainer",
    validator: {
        validates: {
            requiredIf: function (val, condition){
                return val && condition
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        loading: true,
        stationId: stationId,
        date: initialDate,
        dateFormatted: initialDateFormatted,
        nextDate: null,
        prevDate: null,
        entries: [],
        requestEntries: [],
        roles: [],
        roleStaff: [],
        showObserverEntry: false,
        startPickerDatetime: null,
        endPickerDatetime: null,
        shiftEntry: {
            start: null,
            end: null,
            role: null,
            member: "",
            observer: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: ""
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        validField: function () {
            return this.validation.shiftEntry.observer.firstName.valid &&
                this.validation.shiftEntry.observer.lastName.valid
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getRoleStaff: function () {
            if (this.shiftEntry.role != '' && this.shiftEntry.role != 'observer') {
                this.$http.post('/members/schedule/manage/json/roles/staff', {id: this.shiftEntry.role})
                    .success(function (data) {
                        this.$set('roleStaff', data.members);
                        vm.shiftEntry.member = "";
                        vm.showObserverEntry = false;
                        vm.shiftEntry.observer.firstName = "";
                        vm.shiftEntry.observer.lastName = "";
                    });
            } else if (this.shiftEntry.role == 'observer') {
                this.showObserverEntry = true;
                this.resetFields()
            }
            else {
                this.showObserverEntry = false;
                this.roleStaff = [];
            }
        },
        resetFields: function () {
            this.roleStaff = [];
            this.shiftEntry.role = "";
            this.shiftEntry.member = "";
            this.shiftEntry.observer.firstName = "";
            this.shiftEntry.observer.lastName = "";
        },
        conditionalField: function (response, type) {
            return response === type
        }
    }
});
```

Form fields:

```
<div class="form-group"
                                 v-if="conditionalField(showObserverEntry, false)"
                                 v-class="has-error: validation.shiftEntry.member.invalid">
                                <label for="member">Member:</label>
                                <select name="member"
                                        id="member"
                                        v-model="shiftEntry.member"
                                        options="roleStaff"
                                        v-attr="disabled: !roleStaff.length"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        v-validate="requiredIf: conditionalField(showObserverEntry, false)">
                                    <option value="">Select Member</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 v-if="conditionalField(showObserverEntry, true)"
                                 v-class="has-error: validation.shiftEntry.observer.firstName.invalid">
                                <label for="observer_firstName">First Name:</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                       id="observer_firstName"
                                       class="form-control"
                                        v-model="shiftEntry.observer.firstName"
                                        v-validate="requiredIf: conditionalField(showObserverEntry, true)">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 v-if="conditionalField(showObserverEntry, true)"
                                 v-class="has-error: validation.shiftEntry.observer.lastName.invalid">
                                <label for="observer_lastName">Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                       id="observer_lastName"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       v-model="shiftEntry.observer.lastName"
                                       v-validate="requiredIf: conditionalField(showObserverEntry, true)">
                            </div>
```

Comment: This is a complex enough scenario where a JSFiddle would probably help.

Comment: Working example of what I'm trying to accomplish but not using the vuejs-validator library - https://jsfiddle.net/6gpryhep/. In the example, if `observerShift` (computed) is false, `shiftEntry.member` is required. If it is true, `shiftEntry.member` is NOT required but `shiftEntry.observer.firstName` and `shiftEntry.observer.lastName` ARE required. So, conditionally required fields based on a boolean value (observerShift). If that doesn't make sense I'm at a total loss ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is because a bug in Vue.js. Reason: If we remove one or more v-model based on certain condition(v-if), then it will make all other validation to deactivate.

Refer the issue :https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/issues/69

Comment: I understand the issue will be fixed in version 2.0.0
Since this version is still in alpha stage, is there any workaround?
I'm in need of conditional requires as well.